# Log File ownership in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2.18
Ruby 2.15
```

I inherited a Rails application that I am trying to decipher. In environments/production.rb, I have:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 100, 10485760)
config.log_tags = [ lambda {|r| DateTime.now } ]
```

which is going to create a log file in the log folder and when it reaches 10MB it ages it and keeps 100 in the folder.

When I look at the folder, I see that the owner of these files is root. How do I make sure the owner is the user and not root? For instance, if the application is deployed in /home/myapp, I want the owner to be the myapp user. The real side issue I'm having is that if I am logged in as the myapp user and try to precompile assets, it fails because the log file is owned by root.

Comment: Is the app being run as root?

Comment: No the app is not being run as root. It is run in the home directory of the app

Comment: Where it is doesn't matter - how are you running it?

Comment: The app is most likely being run as root because it will be running on port 80 or 443

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are always a pain.  You'll likely want to run something like this:

```
sudo chown -R myapp_user /home/myapp
```

or

```
sudo chown -R myapp_user:myapp_user /home/myapp
```

if you want the group to be set as well.  This requires the user you are running as to have sudo permissions.  If you don't have sudo permissions you'll have to login as root and execute the command above.

Comment: I do that, but then it automatically changes ownership of production.log to root. Some of the Capistrano tasks stop working as a consequence

Comment: What changes it to root?  When?  Rails doesn't automatically change ownership of the file so some process that is being run as root is taking control of the log file.  You have to either run everything as root or find the process that is running as root and configure it to not run as root or to not change the ownership of the log file.

Comment: @JoeM The stack will be running as root and therefore creating the log files as root user. Changing the permissions manually isn't a viable long term solution